# Requests are getting failed with error code 499

Tags: jmeter

Requests are getting failed with error code "499" when application is loaded with 1000 users with ramp-up time as 150 seconds using jmeter.
could not find any error in jmeter.log in bin folder.
it would be great help if some pointers for this failures?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Status code 499 [isn't listed in the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231.html#section-6.1) so you need to see your application logs to know what it means and what could be possible cause.

If you're using [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) as the backend [status code 499](https://httpstatuses.com/499) means that the client (in your case JMeter) has closed the connection in the middle of communication, most probably due to timeout so if response times are higher than your configured or default timeout - it may be the cause of the issue, consider increasing connect/response timeouts, the setting lives at "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element

[image]

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, Thanks for response. we have not mentioned explicit timeout for any of request, so just wanted to know what is default response timeout in jmeter?

Comment: Default is "no limit", however the limit may be actually set by underlying JRE and OS sockets configurations so it's better to set something there

Comment: Increased connection and response timeout to 300 seconds... but it fails with 499 error only. while execution is in progress, if we manually browse the application via chrome browse, it fails with "499" error for same request. Kindly suggest what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: If it happens only under the load - it's your application problem. I gave you a piece of advice: see your application logs, if you're ignoring this I don't see any sense in continuing supporting you

Comment: we looked at application nlogs and could able to see request getting processed and response being generated. but somehow its not getting reached to client. Anyhow thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late.. If you triple (like pressing on Ctrl + R for 10 seconds) refresh a page in the browser, you would get a 499 on nginx, that means the client prematurely closed the connection. This has nothing do to do with how you application is behaving its mainly a client closing before actually waiting for a response. This could also lead to a broken pipe in some other circumstances.